# Recaptcha secret key, where is it in my Google Cloud Recaptcha account?

Tags: recaptcha

I am attempting to setup a google recaptcha on my site and the plugin I am using is asking for the site key AND a secret key. No idea what a secret key is, I cannot find it in my settings anywhere in Google Cloud. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Una, welcome to Stackoverflow, you can find detailed information about creating Site Keys and API Keys on Google Console here: https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key?hl=en

Comment: I have the site key created (and have that info already in my plugin) - I just don't know where to find the secret key my plugin is also looking for. The tool won't work as it is setup now. Your link doesn't show any reference to a secret key...

Comment: If you create a recaptcha , you will shown the site ID and secret key. Please note them and keep them safe from anyone else. If you did not save them, you can view them on google console, or you can create a new recaptcha here: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create

Comment: Is this a downloadable file or something? It showed me my site key, but never a secret key.

Edit: I clicked your link, created a new one, and it showed a secret key, but this Recaptcha doesn't show in my Google Cloud anywhere. How can I get back to it in the future if I ever need to? Also, my recaptcha still isn't working with this info input.

Comment: No it is not, it is a string composed of letters and numbers just like your site key. If you go to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/ , choose the website you created your API keys for, and click on cog wheel on the right upper corner,  You will see recaptcha type and `reCaptcha` keys, click on that to view keys you have created. It shows you Site key AND secret key.

Comment: OK well a v3 didn't work, but a v2 did work. Thanks a million for the help!

Comment: @Bijay Regmi I don't understand why you didn't post your comments as a true answer

Comment: The question of how to find your secret key when a key is created in enterprise isn't answered.

Comment: It is now possible to find your secret key in the Google Cloud Console
If you go to the details page of your site key, the secret key will be available at the bottom.

https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/faq#i_use_a_third-party_plug-inimplementation_that_does_not_formally_support_but_only_legacy_recaptcha_can_i_still_use

Answer (score 3):

Updated answer with latest UI change.

It is now possible to [find your secret key in the Google Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key-website#find-key)

You can find it in the GCP web console by clicking the Enterprise Key's Overview -> Integration Tab -> "USE LEGACY KEY" text at the top of this tab view.

Comment: The [how-to-find legacy secret key FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key-website#find-key) is outdated as of this comment.

You can still find it in the GCP web console by clicking the Enterprise Key's Overview -> Integration Tab -> `USE LEGACY KEY` text at the top of this tab view.

Comment: Thanks. Updated my answer with an updated link and description.

Answer (score 3):

Even I faced the same confusion after trying to implement it by reading some online tutorials. The first confusion was why my Google Cloud console called it CAPTCHA "Enterprise". But I will leave that exploration to you, as it doesn't matter in our case.

But I was finally able to get it to work. I found the secret under,
**Legacy reCAPTCHA secret key**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try going to https://g.co/recaptcha/v3 and use that UI to set up your reCaptcha. With that process I was provided with two keys, a site key for the frontend and a secret key for the backend.

Google seems to have a couple of different ways to set up recaptcha and the documentation is out of sync with reality so there are many dead ends to get lost in. I spent a long time in the Google Cloud Platform and it was useless.

Answer (score 0):

The ReCAPTCHA Enterprise version does not use a secret key. You can still use recaptcha 3 or 2 and generate a api and secret key here:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/create
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a bit late to answer your question, but you can find the keys you're searching for here:

1. Go to this link: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/ and go to the nav bar. Click on "v3 Admin Console"; it will show you the projects that use the API.
2. Watch the nav bar where your project name is located and click on "Settings".
3. Now you will be able to see the settings of your site. Click on the option "reCAPTCHA keys"; it's located between the button "VIEW IN CLOUD CONSOLE" and the label "Domains". And you're done!

Answer (score -1):

Enterprise ReCaptcha is a bit different than the standard one.

1. Login to Google cloud platform and select your project from the top menu.
2. Search for reCAPTCHA Enterprise in the search box.
3. On that screen you can definite Enterprise keys (public site key) and their settings (allowed domains, etc...)
4. In order to create a secret key, go to: APIs and services menu. Select 'Credentials' and define a new API key (secret key).

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't know why you're downvoted — you're absolutely right. API keys can be created here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials