# can't find recaptcha v2 site key and secret in google console.cloud.google.com

Tags: google-cloud-platform, recaptcha

A long time ago I've created the site key and secret for recaptcha v2 in the google cloud console.

Now all I can find there is `reCAPTCHA Enterprise API` with an `ENABLE` button,

the recaptcha on my site still works, but I can't find it's secret and key values on the google console.

I wanted to add another site key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the secret key which was created long back by following this [Find a legacy reCAPTCHA secret key](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key-website#find-key). Under the integrations, you can find the secret key. Note that if those keys are deleted then you  cannot recover deleted keys. In order to check the keys you need to Enable recaptcha Enterprise API.

There is no limit on the number of reCAPTCHA keys that you can create for a Google Cloud project. It is best to create one reCAPTCHA key per website. You can create a new sitekey by following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/create-key-website#create-key).

- You can also check this [blog](https://www.positronx.io/how-to-get-google-recaptcha-site-key-and-secret-key/) by Digamber for more information.
- I recommend you to use recaptcha enterprise  only as it helps/ protects your website from fraudulent activity, spam, and abuse without creating friction and this is having more features Compared to v2 and V3.
- The different features in each version of reCAPTCHA can be seen in this [documentation](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) and [Compare versions documentation](https://cloud.google.com/recaptcha-enterprise/docs/compare-versions).

Comment: and is there a way to see the legacy (or classic) secret

Comment: On the Key Details page, under the Integration tab, click Use Legacy Key. A dialog opens with instructions on how to use the legacy secret key. You can see the legacy secret  also.

Comment: where do I find the key details or the integration tab ?

Comment: @buga : Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73169174/19230181) by Shivu D.G. You can get the key as shown in screenshot .

Comment: well the problem is that the "Classic keys" table the row with the key in it has no "details" button, it only has a "copy to cliboard" button and that's it, probably in 2022 there was a details button

Comment: well, at least I found the key, no idea where the secret is, but I don't really need it now, guess next time I'll use v3 or hCaptcha